# Why do higher-end desktop motherboards tend to have more metal covering the circuitry?

Tags: motherboard

I've noticed that with desktop motherboards that are higher-end (more expensive) tend to have more metal covering the circuitry than lower-end (cheaper) boards.

For comparison:

MSI MAG B650 TOMAHAWK WIFI ATX AM5 Motherboard ($220)
[image: Cheap motherboard]

MSI MEG X670E GODLIKE EATX AM5 Motherboard ($1300)
[image: Expensive motherboard]

My intuition tells me that this is an aesthetic choice  as it seems that most of the components that generate heat on both boards are already covered. Is my intuition correct or is it done for another reason?

Comment: I doubt it is for aesthetics  - Manufacturers watch costs.  Likely for shielding.

Comment: And to redirect airflow and transfer heat more rapidly. RAM and SSD heat may be significant, where originally all air was needed on CPU, and later, GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of it is aesthetics, but at least a few parts are active heatsinking.

[image]

Above and to the left of the CPU are heatsink blocks for the CPU power regulators.

You'll also notice both motherboards have similar heatsinking in the areas I highlighted above. The more expensive motherboard may well have another m2 slot, hence why the lower m.2 heatsink spans the length of the board. There are two m.2 slots next to each other under the larger heatsink.

To the left of the CPU is also an area that contains a lot of high speed USB 3 connectors, the large shield beside the regulators will be an [RF shielding can](https://resources.altium.com/p/pcb-emi-shielding-using-cans). These are used to limit the amount of leaked RF noise both from and to high speed components preventing them from interfering with other electronics and preventing other electronics from interfering with them.

The more expensive board appears to have a second "can" to the right of the memory DIMMs, it is entirely possible that there is more USB 3 chips there, or power supplies for case RGB lighting, or something else.

While aesthetics plays a part, more often than not these things do have a purpose beyond just looking pretty.

All of the intricate detail work does play a part in selling one board over another though. In the modern age of RGB lighting and glass cases there is a very significant group who want their motherboards to "look cool" so while all those parts do actually serve a purpose all the embellishments serve a secondary purpose of selling the product as well.